# How to get the "nth best" records in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I know how to query the top 10 records:

```
SELECT name, score FROM mytable ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10
```

But what if I'd like the second-best (or nth-best) 10? I guess I could do something like

```
SELECT name, score FROM(    
SELECT name, score FROM mytable ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 20) 
ORDER BY score ASC LIMIT 10
```

But this seem needlessly inefficient. Is there a more idiomatic way to return, say row 11 to 20? (I'm more familiar with Pandas, where I'd do this with an index.)

The use case is that I'd like to export data from the middle of the table, but it's too big to download all of it starting from the top

Comment: This might help

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/analytic-function-concepts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ORDER BY` takes an `OFFSET` clause as well. Here's an example you can try:

```
WITH T AS (
  -- Returns x values of 1 to 100
  SELECT x
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 100)) AS x
)
SELECT x
FROM T
ORDER BY x LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10;
```

This returns the 11th through 20th rows based on the sort order. You can try changing the limit or offset to see different results.